# Send an email with a HTML file as body. Parameters such as name, email address etc need to be injected into the file when the email is sent

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an HTML template saved as a file. Basically what I want to do is trigger a Welcome Email whenever a customer buys a product. The email body will be same as the HTML file saved. Currently, I am doing it the following way.

My cs file looks like this:

```
public Task<EmailResponse> SendEmail(EmailRequest emailObject)
        {
            var response = new EmailResponse();
            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient
            {
                EnableSsl = false,
                Port = 
                Host = ""
            };

            var Message = new MailMessage
            {
                Subject = ,
                From = new MailAddress(emailObject.FromEmail, emailObject.FromName),
                IsBodyHtml = true,
                Body = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(emailObject.Html)
                };
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use SMTP.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("yoursmtp.com");
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("xyz@xyz.com");
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Subject = "Your " + Name + " User Access information";
mail.To.Add(obj.config.data.email);
mail.body = "<html><body><p>Hi" + " "+ obj.config.data.firstName + ","
+ "</p><p>Below is your user name and password to access the " + Name +" application.</p>....
smtp.Send(mail);
```

I would modify the way you are concatenating your strings. You could you

```
$"Your {Name} User Access information";
```

And same thing for the body.

Comment: But I want the mail to be as per a saved html file. Basically the file will be read into memory and then name, email etc. will get replaced with the required information.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get that right, so do you want the body to be an html file and read it in your program? or do you want your program to generate the html file?

Comment: The body content should be read from a HTML file. I tried using  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/expo_crm/test/HTMLPage.htm")); but it's giving an error saying that Server does not exixt in the current context.